# How do I iterate through an XML in C# and populate a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML similar to this:

```
<Account>
  <Personal>
    <Name>TestName</name>
    <address>TestAddress</Address>
  </personal>
  <details>
    <House>
        <Foundation>
            <Severity>0</Severity>
        </Foundation>
        <StepsFront>
            <Severity>-1</Severity>
        </StepsFront>
        <StepsRear>
            <Severity>-1</Severity>
        </StepsRear>
        <StepsSide>
            <Severity>-1</Severity>
        </StepsSide>
        <PorchFront>
            <Severity>0</Severity>
        </PorchFront>
    </House>

  </details>
</Account>
```

I can get the Personal details easily enough, but I'd like some way to populate a Dictionary with the items in House dynamically since these could change, like this:

```
Foundation 0    
StepsFront 3    
StepsRear  1    
StepsSide  3    
PorchFront 2
```

I've tried doing this a few ways, using LINQ to XML with XDocument and XElement, but nothing I've used has been giving me anything close.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.95).aspx) method:

```
XDocument document;
...
var house = document.Elements("House").First();
house.Elements().ToDictionary(e => e.Name, e => e.Element("Severity").Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, int> severities =
    doc.Descendants("House").First()
    .Elements().ToDictionary(
        e => e.Name.ToString(),
        e => int.Parse(e.Element("Severity").Value));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.